# Get html table row information when it's corresponding radiobutton is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing a web page and one of the tasks I want it to do is show in textboxes the information provided in a table (whose data is determined by a query in MySQL) when the user clicks its corresponding row's radio button.
I managed to get it to work, but it only works one time. How can I make it work every time?

Thank you so much!

HTML and PHP Code:

```
<table style="width=100%;border: 1px solid black" id="tablaListado" cellspacing="10">
        <tr style="border-bottom-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#1e1e1e;text-align: -webkit-center;background:#22CECE;font-size: 16px;">
            <th style = "border: 1px solid black">Elegir</th>
            <th style = "border: 1px solid black">SKU</th>
            <th style = "border: 1px solid black">ISBN 13</th>
            <th style = "border: 1px solid black">Titulo</th>
            <th style = "border: 1px solid black">Proveedor</th>
            <th style = "border: 1px solid black">Costo</th>
            <th style = "border: 1px solid black">Precio</th>
        </tr>
        <?php 
            $result = faltanteCostos();

            if(mysql_num_rows($result) >0){
                while($registroDD = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

                        echo "<tr style='border: 1px solid black'>
                            <td style='border: 1px solid black'>
                                <input type='radio' id='regular' name='optradio' onclick='llenarInfo()'>
                            </td>
                            <td class='sku' style='border: 1px solid black'>".$registroDD['art_SKU']."</td>
                            <td class='isbn13' style='border: 1px solid black'>".$registroDD['art_N13']."</td>
                            <td class='titulo' style='border: 1px solid black'>".$registroDD['art_titulo']."</td>
                            <td class='prov' style='border: 1px solid black'>".$registroDD['art_id_proveedor']."</td>
                            <td class='costo' style='border: 1px solid black'>".$registroDD['art_cost']."</td>
                            <td class='precio' style='border: 1px solid black'>".$registroDD['art_precio']."</td>
                        </tr>";

                }
            }
        ?>
    </table>
```

JS:

```
function llenarInfo(){
        var d = document.getElementsByName('optradio');

        for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
            if (d[i].checked) {          

                document.getElementById("insku").value = $("td input[name='optradio']:checked").parents().find('.sku').html();
                document.getElementById("inisbn").value = $("td input[name='optradio']:checked").parents().find('.isbn13').html();
                document.getElementById("intit").value = $("td input[name='optradio']:checked").parents().find('.titulo').html();
                document.getElementById("inprov").value = $("td input[name='optradio']:checked").parents().find('.prov').html();
                document.getElementById("incost").value = $("td input[name='optradio']:checked").parents().find('.costo').html();
                document.getElementById("inprecio").value = $("td input[name='optradio']:checked").parents().find('.precio').html();
                console.log("yes!");
            }
        }
    }
```

Edit: I will add pictures of what my problem is

[image]

In the picture above I clicked the first radio button and the corresponding information appeared correctly on the bottom.

[image]

In this one, however, when I click the second button and I have clicked the first one before the information doesn't change.

Comment: Why not creating a working example? If it's just about a clicking javascript problem, all we need is HTML, javascript and maybe some CSS. No PHP. Just please read this again: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and edit your question with the relevant code we need.

Comment: You've got an odd mix of jQuery and normal DOM methods. It's best to pick one and stick with it. In this instance, you're calling `$("td input[name='optradio']:checked").parents().find('.sku')` six times, when all you need is `$(d[i]).closest('tr').find('.ski').html()`, although I'm not sure why you'd want to set the value of a form element to HTML; might be better with `.text()`.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan you got me there. To tell you the truth I am a little new on JavaScript, which is why you see this odd mix. Thank you, I will fix it now! :D

Answer (score 1):

Why not do something like this...

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on('click', function(){

    var value1 = $(this).parent().parent().find('.classYouWant').text();
    var value2 = $(this).parent().parent().find('.classYouWant').text();

    $('#idOfInputBox1').val(value1);
    $('#idOfInputBox2').val(value2);

});
```

By the way, you don't want `.html()` from your row, you just want the `.text()`. I also wouldn't use `.parents()` because you only need to go up two levels, so just chain 2 parents.